About adjoint of densely defined linear operator
Let's consider $\mathfrak{H}$ be a Hilbert space, a densely defined linear operator on $\mathfrak{H}$ is an ordered pair $(T,D_T)$, where $D_T$ is a dense linear subspace of $\mathfrak{h}$, and $T:D_T\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ is a linear transformation.
In the text, it says using Rieze representation theorem, for $g\in D_T*$ , there exists ''unique'' element $T^*g\in\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\langle Tf,g\rangle=\langle f,T^*g\rangle$.
I don't know why it should be unique.
Thank for your help!

It's literally in Riesz's theorem: since $f \mapsto \langle Tf, g \rangle$ is bounded and linear, it must take the form $\langle \cdot, h \rangle$ for some unique $h$. We give that unique $h$ the name $T^*g$. Proving the uniqueness in Riesz's theorem is not hard either: if $f \mapsto \langle f, h_1\rangle$ and $f \mapsto \langle f, h_2\rangle$ are the same functional, then $\langle f, h_1 - h_2 \rangle = 0$ for all $f$. What if $f = h_1 - h_2$?

Oh! I got it. Thanks for your clear comments!!
